# Login via Facebook

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I am trying to implement the Facebook login in an Android application, so that the user can login in my application using a Facebook account as well.

I have installed a Facebook application and am using `facebook-android-sdk-3.19.0`.

### Question

I have an `activity` where I have placed my own button, so on clicking on it then I am creating session stuff, etc. to get a session, but when I click on this method then it starts a blank activity own and display a `ProgressDialog`. Please see screenshot. I don't have such an activity in my code so Facebook SDK is doing such so.

```
private static Session openActiveSession(Activity activity, boolean allowLoginUI, List permissions, Session.StatusCallback callback) {
    Session.OpenRequest openRequest = new Session.OpenRequest(activity).setPermissions(permissions).setCallback(callback);
    Session session = new Session.Builder(activity).build();
    if (SessionState.CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED.equals(session.getState()) || allowLoginUI) {
        Session.setActiveSession(session);
        session.openForRead(openRequest);
        return session;
    }
    return null;
}
```

[image]

I don't want this screen. Is there a way to remove this intermediate screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated theme of facebook login `activity` then it is working as usual that I wanted.

```
<activity
    android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">
</activity>
```